# Slow query using < in a table with 4.000.000 rows

Tags: mysql, select

My purchasedItems table with approx. 4 million rows:

```
itemId | orderQuantity | inStockQuantity | backorderQuantity | backorderOrderedQuantity
```

My query:

```
SELECT * FROM purchasedItems 
WHERE backorderOrderedQuantity < backorderQuantity
```

I have indexes on backorderQuantity and backorderOrderedQuantity - and both of them combined. But my query still takes approx. 2-3 seconds.

What can I do to improve the speed?

**Update from comments**

My quantity columns are smallint(3).

The result is very few rows. 20 max.

`EXPLAIN`:

```
Select type: SIMPLE
type: ALL
possible_keys: NULL
key: NULL
key_len: NULL
ref: NULL
rows: all of them
extra: Using where
```

Answer (score 1):

MySQL doesn't support using indexes for `t1.col1 < t1.col2` comparisons. There are already some questions on [stackexchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/33164) that answers your question.

I'd add indexed column `backorder_diff` calculated as `backorderOrderedQuantity - backorderQuantity` (create insert and update trigger that would keep the column up to date without any more housekeeping required from you) and just use:

```
WHERE backorder_diff > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

What you should do:

1. Run `EXPLAIN` on your query:

   ```
    EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM purchasedItems 
    WHERE backorderOrderedQuantity < backorderQuantity
   ```

   to make sure indexes are used.
2. Make sure that backorderOrderedQuantity and backorderQuantity are integers (the best the same type). Probably the should be also as small as possible (if int(1) is enough don't use int(8))
3. Make sure you don't take all the records. I don't know how many records your query return but you should add some limit (10/100) and not return for example 1 million of records - add for example `LIMIT 100` at the end of your query

**EDIT**

I've checked this and it seems that MySQL doesn't use indexes at all on such query so probably you need to create triggers to insert/remove those data to extra table. You could store there for example only itemId (if they are unique)